# R - MLR - randomForestSRC - model size enormous, prediction times very slow - how to reduce both?

Tags: r, random-forest, mlr

Having trained a classification randomForestSRC (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForestSRC/versions/2.6.0) using MLR, the model size is many GBs and the prediction time per instance is extremely slow.

What can we strip out of the model to reduce the size, and presumably reduce prediction time too?

Note some testing shows that predicting 100 items is basically the same speed as prediction 1.

```
**Prediction: 1 observations**
predict.type: prob
threshold: 0=0.50,1=0.50
**time: 70.25**

**Prediction: 100 observations**
predict.type: prob
threshold: 0=0.50,1=0.50
**time: 69.82**
```

https://kogalur.github.io/randomForestSRC/theory.html

Answer (score 3):

There are a few parameters you can tweak to reduce the size of the model. In particular:

- reduce `ntree` for fewer trees
- increase `nodesize` for a larger number of data points per leaf
- decrease `nodedepth` to get shallower trees

Answer (score 3):

If you are not bound to this specific implementation for a classification forest, you might want to give ranger ("classif.ranger") a try.

You can find a comparison of the implementations here:
https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v077i01